# How could I debug multithreaded apps as singlethreaded in VisualStudio

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio

What should I do if I want debug task by task:

```
static void Main()
{
    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(n =>
            {
                var data = LongLoadOperation(n);           // 1.
                var calculation = Calculate(data);         // 2.
                var result = BuildNiceResult(calculation); // 3.
                return result;
            }, number);
            tasks.Add(task);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

I don't want to switch from task to task. It's not very comfortably to debug this code.

Comment: By and large debugging is a less useful tool in a multithreaded app, as you are altering timings that actually affect the output of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprised no one has mentioned this yet... but maybe you should take a look at the "Threads" window or "Parallel Tasks" window (found in Debug -> Windows).  These may help in debugging multi-threaded code.  If you would like to step in each task one by one, set a breakpoint at the beginning of the task. Whenever you hit that breakpoint on each task, go to one of those windows, right click on the thread/task you are executing, and select the option to "Freeze" it. This will stop the thread from executing on its own.  You can use the Threads/Parallel Tasks windows to switch between your various tasks currently executing/frozen. If you want to step through one of the tasks, you can "Unfreeze" it whenever you are ready.  You can actually use these windows to re-create some of those rare race conditions scenarios.

Comment: Someone *has* mentioned it.  [Right here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21606090/1159478)

Comment: I see no mention of freezing/unfreezing threads which was important part I was trying to point out. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

if you place a breakpoint inside task, it will be hit as many time as you have tasks. So you can debug each task at a time but since you are in a multithreaded environment mind that if you stop on thread the others will keep running unless you stop/pause them as well.

A sequence of breakpoints should allow you to create checkpoints in your application.

Comment: When I stop in breakpoint usualy i hit F10 and switch from task to task. That's a problem. When I'm in debug I want to forget about multithreading.

Comment: @backstroker You certainly won't be able to forget about it.  It's an integral part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot determine in which order your threads are getting executed. You might have a complete different order.

Nevertheless, if you want to debug multithreaded applications, you can select a specific thread by selecting it at Debug->Windows->Threads.

If you use the inline syntax for your console.Writeline, you will not see it break there. You might introduce a method for this:

```
{
//...
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod(number));`.
//...
}

private void MyMethod(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Btw, you could use `Parallel.Foreach` to really shorten down your code (I assume you're using something different in your code than Console.WriteLine.):

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
Parallel.ForEach(numbers, Console.WriteLine);
Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

If you want to debug only the thread handling a specific number, you could set a breakpoint condition: Your breakpoint will then only hit if the number matches that condition.